# Getting all the matches with 'grep -f' option

Tags: grep

I would like to find *all* the matches of the text I have in one file ('file1.txt') that are found in another file ('file2.txt') using the grep option -f, that tells to read the expressions to be found from file.

'file1.txt'

a

a

'file2.txt'

a

When I run the command:

grep -f file1.txt file2.txt -w

I get only once the output of the 'a'. instead I would like to get it twice, because it occurs twice in my 'file1.txt' file. Is there a way to let grep (or any other unix/linux) tool to output a match for each line it reads?
Thanks in advance.
Arturo

Comment: *the matches of the text* - some exact text? should it compare line to line?

Comment: Yes it contains exact match. I added the -w options, following your input. Yes, it is a comparison line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep works as designed, giving only one output line. 
You could use another approach:

```
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    grep -e $pattern file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```

This would use every line in file1.txt as a pattern for the grep, thus resulting in the output you're looking for.

Comment: That did the trick!. Thank you. And it is even much faster than my previous grep command.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
grep -f pattern.txt file.txt
```

It means match the pattern found in `pattern.txt` in the file `file.txt`.

It is giving you only one output because that is all is there in the second file.

Try interchanging the files,

```
grep -f file2.txt file1.txt -w
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I understand that, but still I would like to find a way to print a match each time a pattern (even a repeated one) from 'pattern.txt' is found in 'file.txt'. Even a tool or a script rather then 'grep -f' would suffice.